# Invalid object name - system created object

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I wonder if anyone can enlighten me as to the underlying cause of Azure SQL DW errors like this:

> ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Distribution_8.dbo.Table_f8776198af014a96b157b84ce175aa1f_8'

I'm guessing that the object in question is the underlying storage of a table on a particular distribution - but why might Azure SQL DW find itself unable to find it?

I've seen this happen before, and it went away after about 20 minutes with no harm done, but it's pretty inconvenient and I'd like to understand why it happens.

Comment: Were you in the middle of scaling from one DWU to another and continued to run queries or loads? I may have seen this type of error then. If you can consistently repro this error I'm sure Microsoft would like to get your repro.

Comment: Thanks Matt for reporting. Can you share if you were in a scaling operation (resize or pause)?

Answer (score 2):

This error suggests that SQL DW was in the middle of a process of moving things around, such that the table didn't actually exist in the spot that it was expected to be. It should never happen, and you shouldn't really be able to cause that error yourself, even if you were in the middle of a resize or pause, so it's worth raising a support call about it, particularly if you can reproduce the error. Of course, if you were in the middle of doing one of those things, I could say "All bets are off", but still that error shouldn't happen, and you should raise the call with a ton of details about what was going on when you had the error.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. This was straight _after_ a scaling operation, but not during it. I raise the service level objective from 100 DWU to 1000 DWU immediately before running the ETL, and then lower it again afterwards.

I'm doing the scaling using T-SQL with a 2-minute WAITFOR issued straight after it in order to ensure that scaling is complete before I run the next query.

If this is a symptom of scaling, then there's no particular reason not to extend that WAITFOR to 3, 4 or 5 minutes just to make sure that everything's clear.

Comment: @MattConnolly have you continued to use this approach? I find scaling can be 1-15 minutes so I'm skeptical that assuming a fixed time for scaling will work. Maybe sleep 1 minute, check the row count of "select * from sys.dm_pdw_nodes" then loop until that DMV indicates the scaling is complete? Then sleep another few minutes? Thoughts?

Comment: @GregGalloway that sounds like a good idea, but my company has plumped for AWS over Azure, so I'm now migrating the data from Azure SQL DW to Redshift, and unfortunately will probably now never look at this issue again.